# Views 2: Filter Nodes by selected language

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, internationalization, translation, drupal-views

I have a Drupal 6 multilanguage installation and I want to filter the nodes displayed by a view based on the language the user selected.

When adding "Node translation: Language" but I still get all entries. Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: Did you add the language as a filter?

Comment: Ok, sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks, that was the hint I was missing.

Comment: Can you please post this as a solution? I'd like to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Views you can select at the Filters-> "Node translation: Current user's language"

This gives the nodes that are published in the language of the current user.

---

If you are using the i18n module, there is a filter called "i18n: Content Negotation" which handles the appropriate language for you.